# Automation of ssh login using private key through powershell for Linux?

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh

I am trying to automate ssh login to remote red hat vm. I am able to log in but it first prompt for yes/no and then ask for passphrase? Anyone know how to do that using Powershell script to enter yes automatically and passphrase as well...

I tried to use 'echo' with pipeline but it prints yes before prompting it...

thanks!!

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no <host>` and the fingerprint accepted automatically.